# Display data from sqlite database in listview instead of toast?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout

Is it possible to display the following data from sqlite database in a listview instead of a toast as shown in the code below ?

```
btnlist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlist);
    btnlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            handler = new Datahandler(getBaseContext());
            String getName, getaddress, getDate, getTime, getSchoolName;
            getName = "";
            getaddress = "";
            getDate = "";
            getTime = "";
            getSchoolName = "";

            handler.open();
            Cursor C = handler.returnData();// return actual data from
                                            // database
            if (C.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    getName = C.getString(0);
                    getaddress = C.getString(1);
                    getDate = C.getString(2);
                    getTime = C.getString(3);
                    getSchoolName = C.getString(4);

                } while (C.moveToNext());
            }
            handler.close();
            Toast.makeText(
                    getBaseContext(),
                    " Name :" + getName + "Address :"
                            + getaddress + "Date :" + getDate + "Time :"
                            + getTime + "School :" + getSchoolNname,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Simply use `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Comment: do you know how to do it ? I'm getting it wrong

Answer (score 0):

By list view I'm assuming you mean the first row to have the name, second row to have address, third to have date and so forth?  If so I would suggest that you actually make 10 textviews, 5 for labels, and 5 for data.  You can put them into a scroll view if you need scrolling.  Once you have these text views call .setText(...) on the 5 ones with data to populate them with the data you have in the variables such as getName.

The reason I say to do this is to stay more consistent with typical Android design.  Typically list views are used to show lists of data where each row shows different values for the same key such as your contacts.  It looks like you will always have five data points so we don't need the overhead of a list view and a static set of text views will serve this purpose just fine.

Comment: OK, But i just want to list all data from the database in a listview

Answer (score -1):

yes of course its possible :)

You've already done the hard work of getting the data out of the database.

I've put together a super quick example for you. Obviously you'll need to fill in the gaps by reading about a bit and following a few tutorials. Here's a good start:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

http://webdeveloperpadawan.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/android-listview-with-differing-rows.html

What you need to do is create a custom object for your student details or whatever they are. Then instead of doing

String getName = C.getString(0)

you would do something like this:

```
List<Student> students;
Student student;
do{
    student.setName(C.getString(0));
    ...
    //Then you add that student into a List of students
    students.add(student);
}
```

Then create a custom adapter which extends your list of students:

```
public class AdapterStudents extends ArrayAdapter<Student>{
    //...
}
```

Then you create an instance of your adapter and finally just set that adapter to your listview.

As I say follow a few tutorials for more specifics but there's your basic plan of action :)

Good luck.

Comment: For database data with a `Cursor` a `CursorAdapter` is a better option: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Comment: public Cursor getDatahandlerCursor(Context context) {
   SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
   queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
   
   Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(DATA_BASE_NAME, new String[]{
     etName,
     etaddress,
     et_Date,
     et_time,
     etSchoolName},
     null,null,null,null,null);
   return cursor;
 }
I have done this but i'm getting error in queryBuilder.query